# jQuery Random Item from Array Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am trying to assign a random background color to reach td. I have an array:

```
var randomColor = ["red","blue","green","mint","yellow","lightPurple"];
```

and this function:

```
function setRandomColor(){
    return randomColor[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomColor.length)];
  }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2J8yq/16/

You'll notice that every 2-3 times you run the program, a `td` cell will random be white. Does anyone know why this is? I do not have white in the array as an option. I am not sure why `td` cell's are generating a white background.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Since your `setRandomeColor` function will certainly not yield `"white"`, please post *all* relevant code that is needed to produce your unexpected result

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with `setRandomColor()`.

Answer (score 4):

`lightPurple` and `mint` are not valid color keywords. You get an error such as

> Expected color but found 'mint'. Error in parsing value for 'background-color'. Declaration dropped.

Note the "Declaration dropped." at the end. It means that the browser doesn't understand that rule and hence doesn't assign any background color to the element.

The valid keywords are listed in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-color):

> The list of color keywords is: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, orange, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow.

Comment: Ahh thank you Felix! I just tried what you mentioned and it worked. Thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

OutOfRange. Error??

Suppose random function generated 1 (it generate from 0- 1)
Then multiply it by array length (6)
The result is that u rreferencing element out of range

Array is zero based so last element index is 5 not 6

Comment: `Math.random()` never generates the value `1`

Comment: Also, I think white is not white,  but it is the page background when u reference array[6]

Comment: Yes the white comes from the page background, but `array[6]` is never referenced!

Comment: Thank u@ Bergi, I just figured that 1 is exclusive in math.random